# In Java implementation of Kruskal's algorithm where exactly should we perform Path Compression?

Tags: java, minimum-spanning-tree, kruskals-algorithm, disjoint-sets

While implementing Kruskal's algo in Java using Disjoint sets, should we call path-compression as separate funtion or it should be integral part of the find() funtion?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Path compression and other optimizations like union-by-rank should be applied any time you call the `find` operation on your disjoint-set forest.

One way to see this: from the perspective of Kruskal's algorithm, you just need to be able to call `find` and `union` and have them work correctly. You shouldn't need to worry about the details of *how* you're making `find` and `union` work correctly, just that they do. It's the responsibility of the disjoint-set forest to ensure that everything runs quickly, and so the calls to `find` are where you'll see the compression occurring.

Comment: Thanks. So that means we must perform path compression every time we visit find(). So that for future finds the time required is reduced. Is that correct?

Comment: @DonSam Yep, that's the idea!